# Logic Apps Execute SQL Query V2 Connector Not Returning Data

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I was working on a Logic App when I ran across an issue of the SQL connector not returning anything when it should have.

Upon further review, I found it was because I had two columns with the same name.

Ex: Notice the Email column

```
Select 
A.ApplicationId,
E.Email,
E.ExternalContactId,
E.Email,
A.PrimaryAgentId,
.........
From Table1 A (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Table2 E (NOLOCK) ON E.ApplicationId = A.ApplicationId
.......
```

I just wanted to share incase someone else runs into this and needs a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from my end, I received the same issue.  For demonstration I have used the below query.

```
select id, name, id from demo
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

This is an expected behavior seen in logic apps when we are trying to retrieve same column of same table. I understood this when I tried to do the same with other method and received this error which says Bad Request.

[image]

However, you can achieve this by having the alias for columns.

```
select name as n1,name as n2 from demo
```

[image]

Result:

[image]